# Asymptotics for Mertens function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, zeta-functions

It seems that the cumulative mean of the Mertens function is very similar in behaviour to $x$ raised to the power of the first zeta zero. I tentatively notate it as:
$$\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^xM(k)\right)+2\sim\Im((\text{K}x) ^{\rho_{1}}/\text{c})$$
where $\text{c}\approx64,\ \rm{K}$ is Catalan's constant, $M(k)$ is the Mertens function of $k$, and $\rho_n$ is the nth zeta zero, and the $+2$ on the LHS is to account for the mean of the Mertens function being $\frac{1}{\zeta(0)}=-2$.
Below are plots up to $1000, 10\ 000$ and $100\ 000$.
[image]

The wavelengths are as strikingly similar for small $x$ as they are for larger $x$. It seems to me to be a little too consistent to be coincidental. Has anyone else come across any literature on the subject / or can anyone shed any light on this? Why should it fluctuate with such regularity?

Comment: if all the zeros are simple, then $M(x) = \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho \zeta'(\rho)} - 2$. (this is an explicit formula very similar to the [Riemann explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Riemann.27s_explicit_formula) ) hence you see that when $x$ becomes very large, if $\int_1^x M(y) dy \sim \frac{x^{\rho_1+1}}{\rho_1 (\rho_1+1)\zeta'(\rho_1)}$ depends on the Riemann hypothesis

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if the Riemann hypothesis is satisfied, then the mean value of the Mertens function has the order $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$?